# Jasmine 2.0 unit testing for angularjs factory

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0, angular-factory

I am new to writing jasmine test cases for angularJS factory. 
I want to test the entire factory, but I'm unable to fetch `getKeys`. Here's my factory.

**My Factory is:**

```
'use strict';
var a11yModule = angular.module('TestModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
a11yModule.factory('TestFacotry', ['$q', '$timeout', function ($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        getKeys: function () {
            return {
                "abc": 32,
                "gpa": 33,
                "end": 35
            };
        }
    };
}])
```

**My Unit Spec is:**

```
describe('modu testing', function () {
    var TestFacotryMock, q, timeout;
    beforeEach(module('TestModule', ['ui.bootstrap']));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_, _$timeout_, _TestFacotry_) {
        q = _$q_;
        timeout = _$timeout_;
        TestFacotryMock = _TestFacotry_;

    }));

    it('Should ', function () {
        //var output = TestFacotryMock.getKeys.something();
        expect(typeof getKeys()).toBe('function');
    });

});
```

**Error is**

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module TestModule due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: You don't need to pass `['ui.bootstrap']` while testing, just `beforeEach(module('TestModule'));` should do

Comment: getting same error even not passing `ui.bootstrap`

Comment: Please add ui-bootstrap in your karma-conf.js file as files: [
            'bower_components/*/*/ui-bootstrap.js']

Comment: Same error, after added in `karma-conf.js` also.

Comment: code was in plunker. let me know whats the wrong is.

https://plnkr.co/edit/9VmVWTg5TnvNaAoQ2UB2?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jamin needs to be referenced before angular modules in index.html because angular-mock library has dependency over jasmin.

> load the  libraries like jasmin angular,angular-mock from local folder instead from web

.

```
<link data-require="jasmine" data-semver="1.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css">
<script data-require="jasmine" data-semver="1.3.1" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script data-require="jasmine" data-semver="1.3.1" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>        
<script data-require="angular.js" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-resource.js" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-mocks" data-semver="1.1.5" src="angular-mocks.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="jasmineBootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="addSpec.js"></script>
```

some mistake in unit test

```
it('Should ', function () {

    expect(typeof TestCommonMock.getKeys()).toBe('object');
});
```